# Type must be an interface property

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I feel like I'm missing something extremely simple here - or that it's completely impossible. But given

```
interface ITest {
    prop1: number
    prop2: string
}

const obj: ITest = { prop1: 10, prop2: 'asd' };

const func = (newValue: {???}) => {
    obj = {...obj, ...newValue};
}
```

How can I make it so newValue must be an object who's key name must exist in ITest, and who's value must the the type as defined in ITest[key]. Something like:`{ [key in keyof IEditorStore ]: any }`but the only accepted value type is really only { prop1: number } or { prop2: string }.

Comment: Would restricting the argument type to be `Partial<ITest>` suit your needs? Eg, do you require that the `newValue` object contains one and only one key/value pair?

Comment: Haha, I KNEW the answer was super simple and I was just big dumb. Yeah, Partial<ITest> is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @CRice, If you want to add that as an answer instead of a comment, I'd be glad to put it as the Accepted Answer. Also, after some testing, using Partial doesn't exactly restrict the `newValue` object to contain one and only one key/value pair. I am able to change both value, or more if I add more properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward way to do this would be to use the `Partial` helper and have your argument be of the type `Partial<ITest>`. This will restrict it to be an object with only known keys but doesn't enforce that there is only a single key (or any at all). Eg,

```
const func = (newValue: Partial<ITest>) => {
    obj = {...obj, ...newValue};
}

func({}); // No keys is fine.
func({prop1: 1, prop2: "a"}); // Also including both is fine.
```

If you want to ensure that you don't pass an empty object as an argument, you can change this to require that at least one key always be present:

```
type KeyValueOf<T extends {}> = {[K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K>}[keyof T];

const func = (newValue: KeyValueOf<ITest>) => {
    obj = {...obj, ...newValue};
}

func({}); // This is no longer allowed, produces an error.
func({prop1: 1, prop2: "a"}); // Both keys still allowed
```

I don't think there is a way to prevent both keys being allowed here.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you meant by "I don't think there is a way to prevent both keys being allowed here.", but I am still able to pass either key or both, but not an empty object. Either way, great solution!

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter object contains only one key, how about separating it into two parameters, so you can type them correspondingly:

```
const func = <K extends keyof ITest>(key: K, val: ITest[K]) => {
    obj[key] = val;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=16&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po+rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc+VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtaiKDIKMjJHooACSOH0NAA3ooSiUCGwCABGfKDdiIaQ-dkcrnwAgAJn5glQlE4zEUAF9gghOLKktIAFb8xnM0AAXlALOq3L5oB5AAZ+OKpfyAOQMQTce2gJUAblV8HVNGSXFghtAAB4ANIQ1YKHjCeKQQypPWygB8AAoY3h+SH+DoGNBdUzZQBtEMAXQAlIbE8bRSV4NqC2ni4Hs9BPSrFH7zMn7baefb+ABmUuejuwLu2yV90CDz3FHANDxkLyIeADBgg9g0b5uMzMdgMZiQfiwaDqRJr+B6EReABEAFFVgxEDV9Nekjjr+AHKh7cIAHKQCRryCFQAHlvjIXZBEPLRIGOVBHAUVxpDwUAnGXHRRiwfQUAQRAYWEK4twkFdohEAwOBxboWDYLhuCCEogA)

Comment: This is similar to what I want, but I want my function parameter to be an object, so the input parameter is like { prop1: 10 }